# React With Django, Not auto refreshing without npm run dev

Tags: reactjs, django

I've built React components in Django, but every time I update my react component I have to run
npm run dev + reload the browser to see the changes.

How can I fix this issue to make react refresh automatically after changes?
I have --watch on my script but still doesn't work

package.json

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack --mode development --watch",
    "build": "webpack --mode production"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.12.5",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "webpack": "^5.4.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.2.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.12.1",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.0",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.9.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0"
  }
}
```

index.js

```
import App from "./components/App";
```

App.js

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import {render} from "react-dom";
import HomePage from "./HomePage";


class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="center">
                <HomePage/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;

const appDiv = document.getElementById("app");
render(<App />, appDiv);
```

Homepage.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class Homepage extends Component {
        constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
               test 1
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Homepage;
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is very obvious, you have integrated React in your Django application manually without CRA(create-react-app), and your Django page is isolated from your React application, Django will only detect changes in your `.py` files.

But there are some workaround for this, either you can use this package for your Django app -
https://github.com/fabiogibson/django-livesync

Or you can also try browsersync, which is a little complicated to integrate with Django, but possible.

Comment: Thanks, I managed to fix it tho, I just didn't realize I need to keep the npm run dev, running all the time, and I had a name error in my App.js - instead of Homepage, I wrote HomePage.

Comment: it's good that u could fix it, but it would be better u to write how u fixed it. I "like" such guys

Answer (score -1):

A simple solution is to use the two terminals simultaneously - one for Python `manage.py` runserver and the other for npm run dev.